# statistical data from unix timestamp margin

Tags: php, mysql

I have this database:

```
computername, computerlocation starttime endtime
nameA, locationA, 1457625600, 1457625800
nameB, locationB, 1457625300, 1457625100
nameC, locationA, 1457625600, 1457625900
```

The database is >500,000 rows, contains when a computer was logged onto, then logged off.

At the moment in PHP I run a loop which finds unix timestamps based on selected hours and a range of dates, for example:

- 01/02/2016 9AM
- 01/02/2016 10AM
- 01/02/2016 11AM
- 01/02/2016 12PM
- 01/02/2016 1PM

It will find these hourly timestamps every day for a period of time (around a month) and store them into an array.

I then loop the array, querying SQL every time, counting how many rows where the hour in question is in between the starttime and endtime, I then group by location.

I know how many computers are at a given location (from a separate table), and from the query above how many were actually being used, using this data I work out the utilisation hour by hour, which then gets plotted onto a graph.

My aim is to:

- Only display computers of a given location
- Choose 2 dates (usually a month apart, sometimes longer)
- within those dates analyse computer usage based on specific hours during the day, for example, 9AM - 5PM

The problem I'm finding is looping through every single hour within the selected time frame and selected hours during the day is causing thousands of queries. Is there any way I can achieve this more efficiently using MySQL?

I've tried using a CASE statement, but if a computer is logged onto for multiple hours, CASE will only acknowledge 1 of those hours.

Should I be storing the starttime and endtime in more detail / in a different way?

Comment: Your db table design is ok. What you need is to run some kind of cronjob (for example at the end of each day), that processes results and stores them in another table, where the results will be cached for next use.

Comment: Thanks for this, how would you setup the cache table? I've had a similar idea, but I'm struggling to think of a way to convert starttime - endtime into something that would increase the performance of MySql. Perhaps a column for each hour of the day?

Comment: exactly: columns could be: year,month,day,hour,location,connected_count

Comment: Ok that's what I've done thanks. I have a column in my table mentioned in the question, with an extra column called "cached" where that value is boolean. Everynight a script runs and works out what hours each location was logged into as what time. This is written to another "cached" table which I can query for statistics. Thanks for your help.